# correct syntax in :not() css

Tags: css

I'm using the current code

```
#extra-sidebar , .entry-content:not(#post-262){
background-color: rgba(255,255,255,0.8);
}
```

It actually affects my #extra-sidebar but also my .entry-content entirely.
I would like to make an exception for the #post-262 which is affected by the entry-content

Thank you

Comment: write your css seperately for `.entry-content:not(#post-262)`

Comment: This complete depends on how your HTML looks like.

Answer (score 2):

IE8 and earlier do not support the :not selector.

It's best to just override the class with another class like so:

```
#extra-sidebar, .entry-content{
   background-color: rgba(255,255,255,0.8);
}

.entry-content #post-262{
   background: none;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Would I be correct in guessing that `#post-262` is actually a child of an `.entry-content` element (or the other way around), and that they are not one and the same?

If so, you will need to define a style for `#post-262` that overrides the background colour to the same as whatever's behind the container.

Comment: .entry-content is for all the posts.

Comment: #post-262 is <article id> and entry-content is class

Comment: but if i do this it doesnt work .entry-content {
background-color: rgba(255,255,255,0.8);
}

#post-262 {
background-color: transparent;
}

Comment: What exactly do you think `transparent` is going to achieve? It's like... take a translucent sheet of white plastic and put it on your desk. Everything under it looks washed out, right? Now put some clear plastic on top of that. Does the desk become its original colour again?

Answer (score 0):

Well the way was to use

```
#post-262 { 
  background-color:#previousvalue!important;
}
```

No need to use `:not()` function, `!important` is enough to set priorities.